# jQuery dialog retains old values

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am using a jQuery dialog box. It has a problem that it takes old values when I reopen a dialog.

Is there any way I can reopen a dialog without having the old values?
Can I use modal window instead of a dialog?
Can anyone give me an example how can I use modal window?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I fully understand your problem however I will have a guess!

You can hook into the open or close dialog events and reset the input values.

e.g using open

```
$('#elementId').dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
      //clear input fields here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's working.Since i m not registered user i cant mark your comment

Comment: Then register - its worth it:)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling "destroy" on the close event of the dialog after retrieving the values. This will make sure the dialog re-initializes properly on the next launch. I actually wrote about this problem on my site - http://blog.balfes.net/2013/02/14/properly-cleaning-up-a-jquery-dialog-box-to-prevent-memory-leaks/

Cheers,
Bob